# Windows 2012 BCD process to boot from replicated LUN for Boot from SAN

Tags: windows-server-2012, replication, storage-area-network, disaster-recovery, mbr

For our infrastructure we have a production site and a disaster site with SAN-based replication for the LUNs on the Windows servers. So for our proof of concept we have one server on the production site on one storage array whose boot disk is replicated across the SAN (block-level copy) to the second server.

Due to financial constraints, the DR servers are also the development/test servers during normal operation. So there is actually a second boot from SAN disk on each one for the dev/test OS and one for the DR OS. So during failover testing we use boot manager to select which one to boot from as needed.

During our proof of concept testing we ran into the below error when attempting to boot from the target DR LUN which was a replica of the production server boot LUN.

`File: \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD
Error code: 0xc000000f`

My assumption is that this is due to ARC path to the boot device being stored within the BCD file, so NTLDR is unable to find the boot LUN along the original (production) target paths since the replica is on another storage array on another site.

My questions is, to resolve this problem will it be required to run `bootrec` recovery process on BCD for each DR server during failover or is there any better method to allow the BCD to find the correct LUN along a new path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution was simply to lower the SCSI ID for the assigned DR LUN from 255 to 254.